# Do I need a new rim?

Tags: chevrolet, tires, wheels, equinox

[image]

Hello,

I just had a blowout with my 2016 chevrolet equinox after dropping my kids at school. Its raining so as a result of the blowout I lost control and hit the curb . Currently waiting on roadside assistance. Will I need to buy a new rim or can this one be used? Thanks in advance for the feedback.

Comment: I can't clearly see any major bend, perhaps a better close up of the damaged area would suffice.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I can't see the image at work, so will look when I get home (2nd set of eyes). Damage may not be present on the rim, but might not be readily notable until when the tire is fixed. Just because you hit the curb doesn't necessarily mean you've automatically damaged it though, so we'll hope not.

Comment: I would say if a new tire still seals, then it's fine. It's hard to see if there is any real damage (i.e. beyond cosmetic) to the rim in the photo.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though there's just a bad scuff on the rim. As Spinovious said in the comments, if it will hold air, it's probably good. Since this appears to be a cast aluminum rim, I'd suspect it would crack/shatter before it would bend. Once the tire technician gets the old tire off, they can spin the wheel and see if there is any distortion. I think that's going to be your best bet in figuring it out ... but really, I don't think there'll be an issue with it.